# "Warning: Memcached::setOption() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given" Using Redis Memcached from "Redis Enterprise Cloud" with Symfony 5

Tags: redis, memcached, php-7, symfony5

Following is configuration of my services.yaml of Symfony project, 
[I am trying to store sessions on Redis Enterprise Cloud Memcached]

```
parameters:
   session_memcached_host: memcached-11999.someurl.redislabs.com
   session_memcached_port: 11999
   session_memcached_prefix: test
   session_memcached_expire: 3600 # this is in seconds
   session_memcached_user: abcd
   session_memcached_pass: abcd

services:
    session.memcached:
        class: Memcached
        arguments:
        calls:
           - [addServer, ['%session_memcached_host%','%session_memcached_port%']]
#           - [setSaslAuthData, ['%session_memcached_user%','%session_memcached_pass%']]
           - [setOption, [Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true]]

    session.handler.memcached:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@session.memcached", { prefix: '%session_memcached_prefix%', expiretime: '%session_memcached_expire%' }]
```

**Getting following ErrorException**

```
in var/cache/dev/ContainerIG8bgiG/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php (line 1635)

include_once \dirname(__DIR__, 4).'/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/SessionBagInterface.php';
include_once \dirname(__DIR__, 4).'/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/MetadataBag.php';        
$a = new \Memcached();       
$a->addServer('memcached-11999.someurl.redislabs.com', 11999);        
$a->setOption('Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL', true);        
return $this->privates['session.storage.native'] = new\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage($this->parameters['session.storage.options'], new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler($a, ['prefix' => 'test', 'expiretime' => 3600]), new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag('_sf2_meta', 0));    }    /**
```

If I uncomment following line

```
- [setSaslAuthData, ['%session_memcached_user%','%session_memcached_pass%']]
```

then it gives following warning because it won't support SASL without binary

```
Warning: Memcached::setSaslAuthData(): SASL is only supported with binary protocol
```

**Getting following ErrorException**

```
in var/cache/dev/ContainerNVvLqte/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php (line 1635)

include_once \dirname(__DIR__, 4).'/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/SessionBagInterface.php';        
include_once \dirname(__DIR__, 4).'/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/MetadataBag.php';
$a = new \Memcached();
$a->addServer('memcached-11999.someurl.redislabs.com', 11999);
$a->setSaslAuthData('abcd', 'abcd');        
$a->setOption('Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL', true);        

return $this->privates['session.storage.native'] = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage($this->parameters['session.storage.options'], new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler($a, ['prefix' => 'test', 'expiretime' => 3600]), 
new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag('_sf2_meta', 0));    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why Symfony is considering first parameter 'Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL' as string only when add it in services.yaml!!

I resolved this issue by enabling default memcached.default_binary_protocol

I have added this line in /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/memcached.ini

```
memcached.default_binary_protocol = On
```

[Check this screen shot of info.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Metqu.png)

Following is my final configuration of services.yaml file of Symfony project

```
parameters:
   session_memcached_host: memcached-11999.someurl.redislabs.com
   session_memcached_port: 11999
   session_memcached_prefix: test
   session_memcached_expire: 3600 # this is in seconds
   session_memcached_user: abcd
   session_memcached_pass: abcd

services:
    session.memcached:
        class: Memcached
        arguments:
        calls:
           - [setSaslAuthData, ['%session_memcached_user%','%session_memcached_$
           - [addServer, ['%session_memcached_host%','%session_memcached_port%'$

    session.handler.memcached:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\Memcach$
        arguments: ["@session.memcached", { prefix: '%session_memcached_prefix%$
```

Now it is storing sessions on Redislabs Memcached :)